# Need to unbind local folder from SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN

I imported some file to the server. Then I deleted all imported files from server.
But my folder in windows explorer is diplayed with SVN icon. How can I removed it?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503743/how-do-i-remove-a-folder-from-source-control-with-tortoisesvn

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can right click the folder -> choose TortoiseSVN -> Export and choose the same location as the folder currently is in (i.e. export the folder to itself)

This will 'un-version' the whole folder.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to use the **svn export** command.

Assuming your *working directory* is the root directory of your code:

`svn export . ..\myexportedcode`

To know more about *svn export*

1. [svn export (version 1.7)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)
2. [svn export (lastest)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)

OR a **shortcut** is:

Select the option 'Show hidden files' and delete the .svn folder in your directory.

OR

Comment: This only works if repeat this action recursively for each sub-folder.

Comment: Yes, find `.svn` with in the folder and delete all.

Comment: Unless you're using the SVN 1.7 working copy layount, in which case there is only one .svn directory to represent the entire working copy.  Delete this one, and you've "unbound" the directory structure, to use your term.