# Remove svn from hard drive folder

Tags: svn, hard-drive

Unintentionally I checked out the `C:\` hard drive to get controlled by `SVN`.

Result : All of the sub folders are version controlled.

How can I remove the relation of the `C:` folder to `svn` without deleting anything?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: What is svn client you're using? Check this if you're using TortoiseSVN : [How do I remove a folder from source control with TortoiseSVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503743/how-do-i-remove-a-folder-from-source-control-with-tortoisesvn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you SVN is 1.7+ (one .svn folder in the root of WC) just delete `C:\.svn\` folder

Open View > tick on Hidden Items to look for the folder

Comment: Thanks. Cannot fins such a folder. I use svn 1.8

Comment: @user3165438 - but why you wrote "I checked out the C:\ hard drive"? If you don't have metadata-folder - C is NOT Working Copy and NOT versioned

Comment: So what is the problem? Each folder in C:\ has the `Update` and `commit` options on right click. `Checkout` is missing. Even when I create a new folder this is the status. Doesn't it means that the main C:\ is version controlled? Thanks.

Comment: @user3165438 - " Doesn't it means that the main C:\ is version controlled?" No, it does not mean. You can find root (or roots) of WC by hand: use `svn info` inside any such versioned folder and check "Working Copy Root Path" value - in this folder you'll find .svn and removing this folder **effectively unversion** nested tree

Comment: @user3165438 - just read `svn info` (issiead in any dir) output

Answer (score 0):

You have an "Export" option in SVN. That may help.
You can have a folder with no svn relations using export.
Hope i got your question right and this helps.
cheers

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Isn't it dangerous to do so on the main hard drive folder? To where should I export?

Comment: Nope. IT is not dangerous. But I dint understand how did you end up having your c:\ on svn. Now, you just need to remove all the svn relations and references. So export is what will help you.
Cheers. Do mark as answer or vote up if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: I have tried to export. This action makes me stuck since the folder is no longer related to svn, but I cannot cleanup or fresh checkout. Any ideas?

Comment: That is because your previous command has not completed successfully.
Export is the right way to unlink the SVN relatoinship.

Comment: I do not think this id the reason. The exception I get is related to the export action : `The working copy is corrupt, Try a cleanup`. Thanks in advance!